# does git fetch/pull before bundle create

Tags: git, github

I'm doing a backup script for all my github repositories.
I'm using `git bundle create` to create a single file of my repos.

**Do I need to run git fetch/pull before git bundle create ?** If yes, which one: fetch or pull ?

I don't understand the man:

> This command provides support for git fetch and git pull to operate by
>   packaging objects and references in an archive at the originating
>   machine

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `bundle` main purpose is to allow exchage data between repositories when there is no connection possible between two machines. The git allows to create a bundle which could be transferred somehow offline (e.g. by CD-ROM with carrier pigeon), when the bundle could be used as a source for fetch/pull commands on a remote machine.

The difference between the `fetch` and `pull` is simple. The `pull` == `fetch` + `merge`.

The easiest way to make a backup is to use `git clone --mirror <url>` and then periodically `git remote update`. It will transfer only diffs with minimal traffic.

If you want a single file, just zip the mirror clone folder.